# How to render the array of arrays using React?

Tags: reactjs, sharepointframework

I have an array of string arrays like,
items : [a[],b[],c[],d[]].

I want to render the elements of this array as a carousel using React. The following code doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactCarouselProps> { 
    return (  
      <div> 
       <Carousel>
              {this.state.items.map((list,key) => {
               return(
                 <div key = 'key'>
                   <div>{list.a}</div>
                 </div>
               );
                }
              )}
         </Carousel>
       </div>
    );    
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

working example https://jsfiddle.net/shuts13/cfLxrn15/6/

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.items.map((subArray, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              {subArray.map((subitem, i) => {
                return (
                  <ul>
                    <li>{subitem.value}</li>
                  </ul>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: if it helps you, please correct like right answer or, upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To render a array of arrays you can map the second array too. This way your code will loop the parent array and loop all the child arrays, rendering them the way you want.

Here is a example:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement {
    const flatArray = parentArray.map(
        (childArray) => {(childArray.map((childElement) => <div>Your code here</div>)})
    );
    return (
        {flatArray} 
    );
}
```

or, even better, you can use array flat.function(), like this:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement {
    const flatArray = parentArray.flat().map((childElement) => <div>Your code here</div>)
    return (
        {flatArray} 
    );
}
```

Read more about array.flat() method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. When I use flat(), I get the following error,
 "Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'any[]'"

I have been to trying to fix it, but could not find a solution.

Comment: Its because array.flat() is a experimental feature, so there is no support for this on browsers. If you are using Babel or Typescript the transpiler will add support for this feature (they take your ES6 code and transform it into ES3 code usually). You can also add a polyfill manually in your bundle. My recommendation is to use Typescript/Babel or simply do not use this function, managing poly-fills yourself can drive to errors.